# iTunes Radio stack effect

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, itunes

I would like to have an effect like the one in iTunes radio album/playlist on my UIImageView or UIView. I am not sure how I would start with this. Is there any source code or a tutorial about making this kind of stacked effect and animation where it changes position depending on which is currently being viewed and centered on screen.

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it because I have not posted my code and looked like I didn't even try? I don't know where or how to start that is why I asked this question. I was just looking for some help, an existing source code I can refer to or an idea from experts so I can start off with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can get desired effect with **Parallax scrolling album covers** with UICollectionView. (Inspired by **iTunes Radio**.)

GitHub Repo [link](https://github.com/nrj/ParallaxAlbumCovers)

Comment: Yes you're right. I saw this library before but I have not been able to update this question.